# Why is df.cumsum() giving ValueError: Wrong number of items passed, placement implies 1

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I would like to create a new column called total_amount based on the sum of each amount in each group. I would like the final data set to look like the set below.

company   |   amount  |   total_amount

company 1 |   10000    |    10000

company 1 |   20000    |    30000

company 1 |   30000    |    60000

company 2 |   10000    |    10000

company 2 |   20000    |    30000

company 3 |   10000    |    10000

company 4 |   10000    |    10000

company 4 |   20000    |    20000

company 5 |   10000    |    10000

company 5 |   20000    |    30000

company 5 |   30000    |    60000

company 5 |   40000    |    100000

---

I ran this code

```
 df['total_amount'] = df.groupby('company').cumsum()
```

and it worked briefly but when I tried to change its position to make my code more readable, it started giving me KeyError "total_amount" and the value error listed above. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indicates `cumsum` returns more than 1 columns. In other words, `df.groupby('company').cumsum()` is calling `cumsum` on `DataFrameGroupby` object, so it returns a dataframe. If the returned dataframe is only 1 column, the assignment still works. However, if the returned dataframe has 2 or more columns, it will failed as your error above. I suspect your first run returns 1-column dataframe, so It worked. However, the 1st run created an additional column. On next runs, it returns n-columns dataframe, so the assignment failed.

Try this to fix your error:

```
df['total_amount'] = df.groupby('company')['amount'].cumsum()
```

Comment: You were correct, I wasn't aware I could specify another column with brackets. Thanks for the help!